# Execute colorbox function onClick in a table?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to open a different ajax modal for each table row clicked.
So I did this:

```
<tr onclick="$.colorbox({href:"ajax.html"});">
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>menu</td>
    <td>chicken</td>
</tr>
```

That, however doesn't work - while this does:

```
<p>Click for ajax function</p>

$("p").click(function () { 

    $.colorbox({href:"ajax.html"});

});
```

[Here's a running example](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/colorbox/example1/)

If anyone could please point me in the right direction I would be extremely happy :)) Thanks everyone!:)

Comment: As colorbox is jQuery plugin. It is good to use jQuery code rather than traditional java script :)                                     Your website is wonderful!

Comment: Thank you, but which website do you mean specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your jQuery selector to the `tr` tags and walaa:

```
$("tr").click(function () { 

    $.colorbox({href:"ajax.html"});

});
```

I tested this by adding the above code snippet to your site via the FireBug JS Console.

The issue with your inline code is that you are using double-quotes more than you should:

```
onclick="$.colorbox({href:"ajax.html"});"
```

Should change to:

```
onclick="$.colorbox({href:'ajax.html'});"
```

Notice the single quotes around the URL. Your code looks like this to browsers:

```
<tr class="" ajax.html"});"="" onclick="$.colorbox({href:">
```

Comment: Thanks Jasper, however my final table will be much larger, and the links will be taken from a MySQL file which will is updated daily. This would require me to update the html file itself all the time and I don't want to do that

Comment: @pufAmuf There are several ways around that, you can add a `data-` attribute to the `tr` tags like: `<tr data-url="ajax.html">` then your jQuery could do this: `$('tr').click(function () {$.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('data-url');});});`.

Comment: @pufAmuf Here is a simple demo using `data-attributes`: http://jsfiddle.net/AYdam/

Comment: Excellent, Thank you 1000000 times :)))))!